# Joining two tables in mysql - One to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in mysql - User (user_id, first_name ....) and login_history(user_id, login_time)

Every time an user loges in, system records the time in login_history.

I want to run a query to fetch all the fields from the users table and the latest login time from login_history . Can anyone help please?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a join then :

```
SELECT *, login_history.login_time
FROM User
INNER JOIN login_history
ON User.user_id=login_history.user_id;
```

And this query gonna give you, all the columns of User and the login_time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have total 382 records in users table and 3793 records in login_history table. I run the following query - SELECT user_details.*, user_login_history.login_time FROM user_details INNER JOIN user_login_history ON user_details.user_id=user_login_history.user_id - This fetches total 3793 results. But I was expecting total 383 results. i.e all the users field + the latest login date

Comment: With a single query I want to fetch the user details and the latest login time of individual user. I am expecting a result like (UserID, First_Name, Last_Name, Last_Login_Time). Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.col1
    ,t1.col2
    ,[...repeat for all columns in User table]
    ,max(t2.login_time)
FROM user t1
INNER JOIN login_history t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.col1
    ,t1.col2
    ,[..repeat for all columns in User table]
```

This should work, assuming `login_time` is stored in a sane data type and/or format.

Comment: You can use `left join` instead of `inner join` if you want a line for the users that didn't ever connect. You will have a null value for login_time for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Following are 2 queries that can help you out to select latest login time with user details

```
SELECT * FROM User C,login_history O where C.user_id=O.user_id order by O.login_time desc limit 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM User C,login_history O where C.user_id=O.user_id and ROWNUM <=1 order by O.login_time desc
```

Comment: You mansion that you want latest login time. This query will give you that result only. It will fetch all user data with the latest login.